# Running ubuntu/debian from USB hard drive in Macosx?

Tags: debian, ubuntu-14.04, usb-drive

I have a macbook pro, just bought western digital externall 500gb hard drive connects through usb. i want to run ubuntu linux from my usb hard drive, as i have no disk space in my Macbook. Is this possible?

I created 2 partitions, BOOT and ROOT in my western digital drive. I tried installing ubuntu, debian, fedora etc.. and several versions and it freezes/crashes during install.

I was able to create EFI boot but installing linux distribution again to USB harddrive is a problem.

It loooks easy but very complicated.

Comment: This question is off topic because it is not a programming issue, try on [su] or [ubuntu.se] instead.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using vagrant.  Here's a great post about how to run vagrant from an external drive.

http://emptysqua.re/blog/moving-virtualbox-and-vagrant-to-an-external-drive/